# Sort alphanumeric column value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have alpha numeric data in the column in oracle database and I need to sort it, I tried with writing function which check number in order by case but it didn't work

```
1 
55
82
u1 
2 
11 
60 
90 
3B1 
3B2 
PORT/0/635
72 
75 
77 
85 
118
```

---

```
order by
(
        CASE 
            WHEN is_numeric(col1) is 1 THEN
                to_number(col1)
            ELSE
                col1
        END
    );
```

### is_numeric is a customized function which check and returns 1 if the value consists of only numbers.

output should be

```
1
2
11
55
60
72
75
77
82
85
90
118
3B1
3B2
PORT/0/635
u1
```

Any Help, Thanks

Comment: can you share input, current output and expected output?

Comment: here case is not working , two different data type output as one becomes number after conversion and other is varchar

Comment: I don't think `is_numeric` is an oracle function. Checking for equality uses `=`, not `is`. Just stating something "didn't work" isn't helpful

Comment: I see two numbers and a string here > `3B1` , two numbers and two strings here > `PORT/0/635`. I'm finding it difficult to understand "*one becomes number*" when there's more than one number.

Comment: What is your definition of "sort by"? You can just use ORDER BY column to sort the column but that, presumably, is not what you are trying to achieve? What are the rules for the way you want to sort this data?

Comment: 9 would be bigger than 13 if you treat those as strings @NickW

Comment: @lemon yes, I know that. What's that got to do with me asking the questioner how they want to sort these values if they don't want to use the natural sort order where  '9' is bigger than '13' in a column that must have a string datatype?

Comment: @lemon values can be any thing, it can be numeric, alphanumeric or alphanumeric with special character. I have updated the my post. Can you please check

Comment: @NickW I have updated my post, by default Order by I am not looking for  as 9 would be considered greater than 12,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[to_number()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html#GUID-D4807212-AFD7-48A7-9AED-BEC3E8809866) supports conversion error handling.

```
select   *
from     t
order by TO_NUMBER(col1 DEFAULT null ON CONVERSION ERROR) nulls last
        ,col1
```

| COL1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 11 |
| 55 |
| 60 |
| 72 |
| 75 |
| 77 |
| 82 |
| 85 |
| 90 |
| 118 |
| 3B1 |
| 3B2 |
| PORT/0/635 |
| u1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c9d9b7e6a17689a7bbf7a115977d3467&hide=3)

Comment: For information: the `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` syntax was introduced in Oracle 12.

Comment: @DannySlor, Thank u for your response, it seems working just want to understand why we have again col1 after the last keyword, is it referring to other column.
order by TO_NUMBER(col1 DEFAULT null ON CONVERSION ERROR) nulls last ,col1

Comment: You're welcome. I added col1 so it will also arrange the non-numbers alphabetically. In the first expression they're all null so there's no defined order.